# Deploying Python functions that compile via Numba on the Google Cloud Platform: state must be maintained

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, numba

I am running timeseries forecasts for multiple products using the [StatsForecast library from Nixtla](https://nixtla.github.io/statsforecast/). It is a brilliant library. Its most attractive feature would be the speed and reliability of its autoARIMA script. According to the documentation, it owes its speed to the underlying functions using Numba to compile the Python functions.

It runs the forecasts at the promised speed on my local machine. However, I deployed the same script a 2nd generation Google Cloud function where it is evident that the autoARIMA is compiled every time it is called.

As far as my knowledge goes, this is because the server less nature of Google Cloud Functions does not allow a function to maintain state. As such, it will never maintain a compiled state.

I need the most simple approach to deploy the script to the Google Cloud platform such that the autoARIMA function can compile. In other words, I need the easiest way to maintain state for the function. My proposal is to use a scheduled Virtual Machine (VM) from the Compute Engine. I believe it should maintain state and allow the function to compile only one.

Please verify whether such an approach would work, share similar experiences and suggest solutions that are better than the current proposal.

### EDIT:

The virtual machine approach will definitely work. However, I am considering different approaches. It seems that one can cache the compiled functions as explained [here](https://nixtla.github.io/statsforecast/docs/how-to-guides/numba_cache.html). So for a cloud function, I might be able to use an external caching service such as Redis or Memcached. The overhead of calling the API to such a cache client might lead to the run-time not improving. Another approach might be to serialize the compiled function and to import it from cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer to my own question as I found a quick, somewhat crude, fix to my issue. Perhaps someone can gain value from my solution.

So Nixtla StatsForecast offers multiple ways of performing forecasts. One can forecast one time series from a single function call, multiple from a single call or one can even use its integration with Dask, Ray and Spark to allow for further concurrent optimization. I am interested in the first two.

Each time a Nixtla forecast object is called for the first time then it compiles its Python components using Numba and caches the compiled function in the `__pycache__` directory. Cloud functions do not provide the option to do so.

Nothing is stopping one from just using the same forecasting object repeatedly after it has been compiled. This works fine if one is just interested in training the model and pushing out predictions and residuals. I am sure there might be limitations imposed by the forecasting object maintaining its own internal state. For now, I have not experienced such limitations as the `fit` method resets everything I need for my application. I think issues might arise of one uses the conformal prediction intervals.

So for the first two approaches, one just needs to run the forecasting object once to compile after which it runs at impressive Numba speeds. Care should be taken to compile it on a small data set with only one time series otherwise compiling takes too long.